# Redirecting to Custom UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my function to redirect

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Okay"])
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Daily"];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];


    }
}
```

[image]

I've set the custom page as Daily but it doesn't redirects..
All i just want the apps to redirect to the custom page after alert view button

Comment: Why in your `AppDelegate` and not in your `viewController`? You are probably displaying the alert from your current `viewController` and nont from your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: AppDelegate is where I code for the UIAlertView , so i thought of doing it together there was no error but it just doesn't redirect just empty like that

@PanayotPanayotov

Comment: u have added the uialetviewdelegate in your.h file

Comment: if you put `NSLog` after `presentViewController:animated:` does it gets printed

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik , i thought it should be M not H

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov, i did next line  NSLog(@"Hello");
But it didn't print. I can't put after the animated cause return false value of void function.

Comment: OK then when you are creating your `UIAlertView` did you set its delegate to self?

Comment: So you see your "Add to Do VC" when you run the app, right?